# Resize image in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The appengine/image package works fine with images stored in Blobstore. However, what would be a good approach to resize images stored in Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same Image Service with the Google Cloud Storage, especially if you use Blobstore API for uploading images.

A sample code in Java:

```
String fullName = "/gs/" + bucketName + "/" + objectName;
Image picture = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromFilename(fullName);
Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(maxWidth, maxHeight);
picture = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, picture);
```

In Go, you can use [BlobKeyForFile](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference#BlobKeyForFile) function:

> BlobKeyForFile returns a BlobKey for a Google Storage file. The
>   filename should be of the form "/gs/bucket_name/object_name".

Comment: I'm not using the Blobstore API. The service requires a Blogstore Key as a parameter. How do I get this from Cloud Storage? Any concrete code snippet would be just awesome.

Comment: There are methods to create a blob key from a cloud storage filename so you can feed it to the blobstore APIs - just like magic. e.g. in java it's called BlobstoreService.createGsBlobKey() or something like that.

Comment: How do you then save `picture` back to google cloud storage inside App Engine?

Comment: You can get byte[] out of the `Image` and save it to the Cloud Store. Just remember to set the correct Content-type (e.g. "image/jpeg") and file extension, or it won't open in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Image cropping functionality is fairly easy to implement these days. You can then do whatever you want with the image - store it back to `Google Storage` or return it immediately to the client.
What's more, you can easily deploy that functionality to any cloud-based serverless solution.I was using `Cloud Run` because it's Docker-based and hence can be ported anywhere potentially.

I have a [service](https://github.com/wnd-engineering/image-cropper) that we use for image cropping based on `nodejs/sharp` and deployed into Google Cloud Run. You can use it as-is. There's nothing project-specific hardcoded in it.