# Is Google Cloud Storage fast enough for serving images to mobile apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cdn

I have been using Google Cloud Storage to save photos that users upload from a mobile app (built with flutter and firebase), recently I had the need to resize/transform images and I wanted to explore if it's possible to do it directly from google cloud storage!

I found this project https://github.com/albertcht/python-gcs-image that you have to deploy on google app engine and if you call it with a bucket and an image it returns a URL to a Google CDN I think (something like this http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/*).

I looked at the code in the repository and the only thing it does is to return the result of `google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url` and I don't understand why I cannot get this serving_url directly from my dart code?

What is the difference between Google Cloud Storage and lh3.googleusercontent.com?? Can I make the same image processing directly from cloud storage?

It seems odd that I have to run an app engine app that just returns a URL? 
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/?

Comment: I have! But it doesn't answer my question!

Comment: And I am actually using it in my app! The problem is that I don't understand the connection between firebase storage and the link that get_serving_url returns? And also I don't understand why firebase storage is a lot slower than the link to the CDN or whatever get_serving_url returns

Comment: Never mind. I misread it. Thought you are looking for options to store images.

Answer (score 2):

The lib use [this api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/). It's in Python 2.7 which have a end of life the 01/01/2020.

Moreover, the image api is available only with AppEngine 1st generation (python 2.7) and not available for the 2nd generation (python 3).

All of this for not recommended you to use this.

The best design today is to perform the resize/crop when the file is uploaded and to store the result in Cloud Storage. Example [here](https://medium.com/@parthaxbhattacharya/image-processing-using-google-cloud-function-10e65eb19d61) and [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/building-your-next-serverless-application-the-complete-guide-98e48f85bd3c)

Then, you only have to serve, from Cloud Storage, the resized/cropped images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! It's kinda sad that you have to save the images on the storage and that implies additional costs

Answer (score 2):

Look @ Firebase Extensions, there is already such an Extension provided there

Comment: I saw it but it has a lot less features than the link returned by get_serving_url - and as a downside it save different sizes of photos on the storage, which means more costs!

Answer (score 0):

What I [found](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#google_app_engine) is:

> The Java, Python, and go Standard environments for Google App Engine
> include the GAE Images API (Java, Python, which can resize, rotate,
> flip, and crop an image, as well as return an image serving URL which
> allows for client side transformations, similar to Cloudinary and
> Imgix.
> This matches my previous understanding and experience as well. `serving_url` is really convenient for image manipulations.

Having said that, as you correctly pointed out, it's first and foremost an AppEngine feature and will require you to use AppEngine in one way on another.

If it's not what you want, you can create a service that will crop your images and deploy it serverless. It's a lot less burdensome that having AppEngine service running 24/7. What's more, AWS had several pre-baked [templates](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/) to do just that - crop images that can be deployed in a couple of clicks.

If you are, like myself, interested in Google Cloud solution I can offer a similar [function](https://github.com/wnd-engineering/image-cropper) that I wrote. It can be deployed in Cloud Run as-is. See details in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377736/resize-image-in-google-cloud-storage/65111825#65111825).
With it you can not only resize the images for mobile, but also map your own domain to the Cloud Run function and put it behind any CDN you like, which potentially can be faster that service from Google Storage. You can find plenty info on the Internet about why full-fledged CND is better than just bare Google Storage.